# 404 error redirect in Spring MVC with java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple Spring MVC application where I want to hande 404 Not found exceptions in my Advice Controller class

Configuration:

```
   public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfig.class};
    }


    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{RootConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class};
    }


    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }


    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
 @RequestMapping(value = "/error/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String error(){return "error";}
}
```

ControllerAdvice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AdviceController {

    @ExceptionHandler(MyOwnException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public String checkoutException(CheckoutException e, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)   {
                return "error";
    }
}
```

I can catch my own exceptions when I manually throw MyOwnException but I can't get how to catch NoHandlerFound exception. I need to send 404 error code and appropriate error.jsp page when there is no controller method to handle request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your webapp is using `web.xml` it's very simple - just add the following (assuming usage of *InternalResourceViewResolver* with prefix pointing at your *WEB-INF* view folder and suffix *.jsp*). You can have multiple error-page elements of other error codes too.

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

If you are not using `web.xml` it's more complicated and you'll have to define and register your own `ExceptionResolver`. Take a look at this [spring.io blog article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) for details on how to do this.

---

(Edit after comment)

If you want to catch the `NoHandlerFound` exception you first have to tell Spring to throw it via [setting a flag in the DispatcherServlet directly](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.html#setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound-boolean-). To do so, in your `AppInitializer` class add the DispatcherServlet definition on top of what you are currently doing to add the flag:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
    //BEGIN OF NEW CODE
    WebApplicationContext context = getContext();
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(context);
    //we did all this to set the below flag
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet",dispatcherServlet );
    //END OF NEW CODE
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
}
```

Then you can catch the NoHandlerFound exception directly in your `AdviceController`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AdviceController {
    //..
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String dealWithNoHandlerFoundException(CheckoutException e, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest)   {
                return "error";
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to catch Spring MVC standard NoHandlerFound exception. Looks like it has not been thrown by default

Comment: @VadOs I've edited my answer to add further info on how to catch NoHandlerFound exception

Comment: thanks for help but it doesn't work (( I see the same standard error page ((

Comment: looks like this configuration doesn't help at all `@Override
protected DispatcherServlet createDispatcherServlet(WebApplicationContext servletAppContext) {
    final DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = super.createDispatcherServlet(servletAppContext);
    dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);
    return dispatcherServlet;
}`

Comment: I've edited my reply. I've also tested it locally that it's working. Please take a look and if you find this helpful please upvote and/or accept the answer.

Comment: finally it works. thanks. the problem was DefaultServletHadlerConfigurer `@Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }` I removed this and it works now